# How does the html5 video tag works

Tags: html

I'm not sure about how the html5 video tag works, Is the video played directly form serve ,its downloaded ?...I couldn't find an explanation  if somebody knows some link to learn about... 
concretamente

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Specifically my doubt is uf the video is downloaded or is played from the server,I would like to find some technichal explanation

Comment: You may want to change the title a little bit. It seems too generic.

Comment: Anything you can browse is downloaded on your computer somehow. No such thing as play from server.

Comment: You can look to [official HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html). Video is still (temporary) downloaded from the server and played, but actual implementation probably depends on the browser.